# Use connect.basicAuth and another middleware at once

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

The code below is 2 middlewares to do some minimum security for my API.

```
// API
var apiRouteV1 = '/api/v1';
app.use(apiRouteV1, express.basicAuth(function(email, token, callback){
    User.authenticateWithEmailAndToken(email, token, callback);
}));
app.use(apiRouteV1, function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.remoteUser._shop.toString() !== req.shop._id.toString())
        next(Error.http(401, 'Wrong user for this shop'));
    next();
});
```

I'd like to merge both of them. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine them into your own middleware that just calls both, e.g.

```
function apiAuth(){
    var basicAuth = express.basicAuth(function(email, token, callback){
        User.authenticateWithEmailAndToken(email, token, callback);
    });
    var shopAuth = function(req, res, next) {
        if(req.remoteUser._shop.toString() !== req.shop._id.toString()){
            next(Error.http(401, 'Wrong user for this shop'));
        }
        else {
            next();
        }
    };

    return function(req, res, next){
        basicAuth(req, res, function(err){
          if (err) return next(err);

          shopAuth(req, res, next);
        });
    };
}

var apiRouteV1 = '/api/v1';
app.use(apiRouteV1, apiAuth());
```

Also note that your original 'Wrong user' checking middleware would call `next` twice in the case of an error, and I have fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

You can 'combine' them like this:

```
var apiRouteV1 = '/api/v1';

var basicAuthMiddleware = express.basicAuth(function(email, token, callback) {
  User.authenticateWithEmailAndToken(email, token, callback);
});

var myCustomMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.remoteUser._shop.toString() !== req.shop._id.toString())
    next(Error.http(401, 'Wrong user for this shop'));
  next();
};

app.all(apiRouteV1, basicAuthMiddleware, myCustomMiddleware);
```

However, there is a subtle side-effect from having to use `app.all()`: Express will insert `app.router` into the middleware chain when you use it. So make sure that you declare any other middleware (with `app.use()`) *before* the call to `app.all()`.

Another possibility, but I'm making some assumptions about how your code is structured which might be false:

```
app.use(apiRouteV1, express.basicAuth(function(email, token, callback) {
  User.authenticateWithEmailAndToken(email, token, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    if (user._shop.toString() !== req.shop._id.toString())
      return next(Error.http(401, 'Wrong user for this shop'));
    next(null, user);
  });
});
```

Comment: Didn't know about app.all(), thank you. That will do the trick. ps: 2nd solution is not possible since the req variable is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Today I stumbled on a snippet that was exactly doing what I was looking when I asked the question.

```
app.use(apiRouteV1, function(req, res, next) {
    express.basicAuth(function(email, token, callback){
        User.authenticateWithEmailAndToken(email, token, function(err, user) {
            if(err)
                return callback(err);
            if(!user)
                return callback(Error.http(401, 'Combo email:token does not match any record'));
            if(user._shop.toString() !== req.shop._id.toString())
                return callback(Error.http(401, 'Wrong user for this shop'));
            callback(null, user);
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

The trick is to call express.basicAuth in a wrapper function. It's quite messy with all those different callback though.

Comment: This totally works, but note that this method will recreate the `express.basicAuth` middleware instance on every request, which is unnecessary. See my answer below.